# Spanish US dialect: es_US or es_rUS?

Tags: java, android, localization, locale

I'm working with an existing code base that has resources defined for the locale `es_rUS`. I'm trying to understand the significance of the `r`, and why it's not simply `es_US`.

The follow up would be how resolution between these two designators will work (in Android, and Java I suppose). If I have resources specified for `en_US`, would a locale designator of `en_rUS` resolve them? Or would it be the other way (which is more general?).

The context of this is building the Android OS, but I don't think that matters for the subject of this question.

Comment: As per the documentation over here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources (Table 2, Row 2) you need to prepend `r` to the region code. So I am not sure something like `es_US` will work.

Comment: `es_US` (and `en_US`, `pt_BR`, and so on) definitely work. That's by far the most common way of doing it (I've never seen the "r" prior to this).