# Luxon locale for spanish in android

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, date, luxon

I am getting the date in string format (09/01/2022 08:45 PM) and i want to get the date using luxon wrt to different locale( our app support both english and spanish)

### **English(Working fine in android and ios) :**

```
 const appointmentDate = DateTime.fromFormat('09/01/2022 08:45 PM', 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a', { locale: 'en-US' });
    console.log('appointmentDay:' + appointmentDate.day);
```

**Output:** MenuPress:1

### **Spanish :**

**iOS**

```
 const appointmentDate = DateTime.fromFormat('09/01/2022 08:45 PM', 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a', { locale: 'es-US' });
console.log('appointmentDay:' + appointmentDate.day);
```

**Output:1**

**Android:**

```
const appointmentDate = DateTime.fromFormat('09/01/2022 08:45 PM', 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a', { locale: 'es-rUS' });
console.log('appointmentDay:' + appointmentDate.day);
```

**Output:** 1

In android we are able to **get date only if we supply locale as 'es-rUS' and not working if we give 'es-US' or 'es-ES', why do we need to append "r"?**, did not find much info in luxon site also (https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#settings)

Note : With Settings class also it works only with 'es-rUS'

```
Settings.defaultLocale = 'es-rUS';
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549917/spanish-us-dialect-es-us-or-es-rus

Comment: Have you tried something like `new Date().toLocaleString('es-US',{year:'numeric',month:'short',day:'numeric'})`? I expect Luxon leverages the built–in *Intl* object, so perhaps this has nothing to do with Luxon and is a bug in Android's implementation of *Intl*. BTW, "Output:1" doesn't show the output, only the code. ;-)

Comment: BTW, leaving formatting to a language code is undesirable. Better to manually format dates (use a library if you like) to suit the page language in an unambiguous format. Not everyone who reads the page in Spanish is necessarily expecting es-US in the same way that not everyone reading pages in English expects a particular regional variant. The difference in date format between say en-gb (d/m/y), en-us (m/d/y) and en-ca (y-m-d) can be confusing, whereas using the month name is not: "26 Sep 2022" might be notionally en-gb but it will not be confusing to anyone who can read English.